# Is there equivalent to java's File.deleteOnExit() in .NET BCL?

Tags: java, .net, base-class-library

Probably I could make an application domain and hook to DomainUnload event, but I'd like to do that on primary app domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no analogue in .net :(

You've got the right idea, you'll need to explicitly delete it.

```
// Delete the previously created file.
File.Delete(filepath);
```